# Unable to decrypt a file using Java that was encrypted using PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, bouncycastle

My customer encrypted a file using the following PHP code snippet

```
$key="c5ff6db1e2f1d27d294047b220516312da1b4ba899035692e893e16815fc1234";

$content = file_get_contents(filename);
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-256-CBC");
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

$cipherText_raw = openssl_encrypt($this->plaintext, $cipher, 
                         $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

$encode = base64_encode( $iv.$cipherText_raw );//Append IV and encode
```

I am trying to decrypt using Java with this code

```
String hexString = "c5ff6db1e2f1d27d294047b220516312da1b4ba899035692e893e16815fc1234";

//Using Bouncycastle (org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex) for Hex to byte
SecretKeySpec secretKey=new SecretKeySpec(Hex.decode(hexString),"AES");

String content = Files.readString(Paths.get("abc.xml"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

byte[] arrDecode  = Base64.getDecoder().decode(content);
//Extract IV
byte[] arrIV = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrDecode,0,16);
//Extract Encrypted Content
byte[] arrEnc = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrDecode,16,arrDecode.length);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(arrIV));
byte[]  xx = cipher.doFinal(arrEnc);
```

The decrypt does not work. I get the below error

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
```

If I use cipher.update(arrEnc) I get load of junk characters.

I am sure I am missing something. Not able to figure that out. I have also tried Bouncycastle with same result -
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "BCFIPS");

Comment: In the PHP code `$key` is not used anywhere.

Comment: My bad. I have modified the code. thanks.

Comment: In the PHP code there is no hex decoding of the key, which is probably an (unnoticed) bug. In the Java code, the key is hex decoded, which results in incompatibility. The PHP code shortens the too long key implicitly (to 32 bytes for AES-256). In the Java code this has to happen explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

As @topaco brilliantly pointed out, PHP is implicitly shortening the key.

Replace

```
//Using Bouncycastle (org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex) for Hex to byte
SecretKeySpec secretKey=new SecretKeySpec(Hex.decode(hexString),"AES");
```

with

```
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.substring(0,32).getBytes(), "AES");
```

Worked like a charm